# Accept User Input in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to accept user input in a python 3 program:

```
name    = input("Enter Employee Name: ")
salary  = input("Enter salary: ")
company = input("Enter Company name: ")
print("Printing Employee Details")
print ("Name", "Salary", "Company")
print (name, salary, company)
```

But when I run the program I get the following error:

```
Enter Employee Name: Tim
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\aws_ec2_termiante_instances.py", line 1, in <module>
    name    = input("Enter Employee Name: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Tim' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're using Python 3 environment?

Comment: Not re-producable on Python3: https://repl.it/repls/OrderlyCanineAddition

Comment: You are using Python2 - you need to use `raw_input("blablubb")` to get strings - input() wil try to `eval()` your input hence the name error

Comment: Use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` -- my guess is that you're using a Python 2 environment

Comment: Reproducable on Python2: https://repl.it/repls/ExcitableDarkredElements

Comment: Whoops! You are correct. Sorry for taking time out of your day. :( It works when I invoke with python3

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with your code.

This is my output

```
Enter Employee Name: Tim
Enter salary: 100
Enter Company name: google
Printing Employee Details
Name Salary Company
Tim 100 google
```

Make sure you are using a correct python3 interpreter.

you can install one here.
https://www.python.org/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong in your code. Its just that you are using python 2.x. 
You must switch to python 3.x. My suggestion is to update yourself, and install python 3.7.

I have a video where you can learn how to install python 3.7 in vscode. It will take less than 3 minutes to install python in vscode. Watch this video ...

https://youtu.be/wWVnc6RByh8